# Cannot resolve method 'getText' in 'ImageView'

Tags: android, android-studio

I am making a WhatsApp clone app and while working with Android Studio, I am getting an error that says - "Cannot resolve method 'getText' in 'ImageView'"
I am new to android studio and don't know how to fix.
Any help would be appreciated.

```
binding.btnSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(!binding.txtUsername.getText().toString().isEmpty())
        }
```

Comment: @Pooja - ImageViews hold images and not text. It is the `TextView` widget that has text. Therefore I don't see how you are trying to get text from an ImageView using `getText()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the element associated with `txtUsername` is actually an `imageView` defined in your layout xml file.
Change it to `TextView` and your code should work fine

Comment: Thanks a lot.... Now my code works completely fine